# Expanding NumPy array over extra dimension

Tags: python, numpy

What is the easiest way to expand a given NumPy array over an extra dimension?

For example, suppose I have

```
>>> np.arange(4)
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> _.shape
(4,)
>>> expand(np.arange(4), 0, 6)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
>>> _.shape
(6, 4)
```

or this one, a bit more complicated:

```
>>> np.eye(2)
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
>>> _.shape
(2, 2)
>>> expand(np.eye(2), 0, 3)
array([[[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.]]])
>>> _.shape
(3, 2, 2)
```

Comment: have you tried pandas ?

Comment: No I haven't, would probably be overkill for what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend [np.tile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

```
>>> a=np.arange(4)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> np.tile(a,(6,1))
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])

>>> b= np.eye(2)
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
>>> np.tile(b,(3,1,1))
array([[[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.]]])
```

Expanding in many dimensions is pretty easy also:

```
>>> np.tile(b,(2,2,2))
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.]]])
```

Comment: "Construct an array by repeating A the number of times given by reps." Yeah, exactly, thanks!

Comment: If i understand correctly, this creates a new array that uselessly takes up a lot of memory, while a simple *view* of the existing array would suffice...

Answer (score 2):

I think modifying the strides of the array makes it easy to write `expand`:

```
def expand(arr, axis, length):
    new_shape = list(arr.shape)
    new_shape.insert(axis, length)
    new_strides = list(arr.strides)
    new_strides.insert(axis, 0)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, new_shape, new_strides)
```

The function returns a view of the original array, that doesn't take extra memory.

The [stride](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) corresponding to the new axis is 0, so that no matter the index for that axis values remain the same, essentially giving you the desired behaviour.