# Number of 2D array to 3D array, extending third dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have 10 different matrix of size `(60, 100)`. I want to put them along the third dimension inside a for loop, so that the final shape is `(10, 60, 100)`.

I tried with concatenate and end up with size `(600, 100)`.

Comment: show us the code you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expanding NumPy array over extra dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580365/expanding-numpy-array-over-extra-dimension)

Comment: I have 10 different matrix of size(60,100)

Answer (score 3):

`numpy.stack` will allow you to concatenate along new axis.

```
arrays = [mat1,mat2,.....]
out=np.stack(arrays, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new array that you fill with your 2D arrays

> new3DArray = numpy.empty(10, 60, 100)

Answer (score 0):

@MahmoudGeMy answer is my favorite. But there is also another way for reference:

```
out = np.concatenate((mat1[np.newaxis,:],mat1[np.newaxis,:],...),axis=0)
```